# Limit %CPU usage to lower MacBook heat

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

After trying to fix some weird sounds coming from the left fan in my 2015 Macbook Pro, I've accidentally destroyed the fan—only the right one works now. I'm now worried that if I use the Macbook at all, the single fan won't be able to cool down my CPUs quick enough and cause damage.

Whenever I use my computer, it always starts to overheat and the fan starts running; to fix this, I've been trying to run `$ top -o cpu` and then `$ kill PID` to stop processes that seem to be the culprits. However, this is far from a permanent solution.

Is there a way to “tell” my computer that it's missing a fan, or at least limit the temperature it will go before it starts to self-modulate? If that's not possible, is there at least a way to limit the total %CPU usage of all processes a user controls (which hopefully will correlate somewhat to lower temperature)?

I've tried to look up some solutions, but everything I've found is just limiting a specific process, not an entire user. I've tried `quota` and `ulimit`, but I'm not confident I know how to use them correctly or if they will even fix my problems

Comment: Some PCs allowed processor limiting in BIOS, but I have not heard of the ability to do that on Macs.

Comment: If this were linux you could simply reduce the maximum cpu frequency. I posit something like this is possible on a mac as well. Relatedly, Intel CPUs will throttle the clock speeds down to protect themselves from dying regardless of OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the overclocking. I am using 'Turbo Boost Switcher' for more than 1 year works fine. Chek: [Turbo Boost Switcher](http://tbswitcher.rugarciap.com/)